# Cannot Import Daemon class

Tags: python, class, unix, import, daemon

I am trying to run a daemon but I am not able to import the module daemon.

My imports:

```
import os
import sys
import time
from daemon import Daemon
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 11, in 
    from daemon import Daemon
ImportError: cannot import name Daemon**

I tried with python-daemon package but it didn't solve my problem. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently file `daemon.py`, that's first in the classpath doesn't contain a class called `Daemon`.

Answer (score 1):

There is just no class named `Daemon`. From [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#example-usage), the basic usage is:

```
import daemon

from spam import do_main_program

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    do_main_program()
```

I guess, you should follow this guidelines.